# Які слова повинні входити до словникового запасу?

Tags: словотворення

Як багато слів знає певна людина? Скільки слів в українській мові загалом?

Для визначення словникового запасу потрібно виділити кожну окрему словникову одиницю. Але постає багато проблем. Наприклад, можуть бути такі **проблеми**:

- Чи вважати однокореневі слова (*гарний, найгарніший, щонайгарніший…*) за одне?
- Чи вважати слова-омоніми за одне?
- Чи брати до уваги відмінювання слова?
- Чи брати до уваги слова з більш ніж одним коренем (*вічнозелений*)?
- Чи вважати субстантивовані слова (*знайомий, черговий, хворий*) одне?
- Чи брати до уваги слова, що вже вийшли з ужитку?
- та інше.

І, власне, саме **запитання**: Чи існують усталені правила або поради до того, які слова обирати для внесення у словниковий запас, а які - ні? Як дане питання, можливо, вирішилося в інших мовах?

Comment: [Словниковий запас](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81) - це термін з чітким визначенням. Словниковий запас — це набір слів, яким володіє людина у знайомій їй мові.  Вам варто переформулювати власне запитання, щоб воно було більш конкретне, краще відповідало тематиці цього сайту і на нього можливо було дати найкрашу відповідь.

Comment: @finesoul, питання полягає в тому, з яких слів варто формувати цей "набір слів". Поясніть, будь ласка, що в питанні не є конкретним або не зрозумілим, аби я мав змогу виправити.

Comment: Можливо вас цікавить лексичний мінімум з української як іноземної. Щось на кшталт того, що [існує для англійської](http://znoclub.com/angliyska-mova/882-leksichnij-minimum-dlya-zno-z-anglijskoji-movi.html). У Вас зараз  занадто багато запитань в одній темі. Треба лишити лише одне запитання. Також бракує спроби провести власне дослідження і його результатів.

Comment: @finesoul, ваша зауваження є слушним. Проте запитання лише одне і воно висловлене в останньому абзаці: _"Чи існують усталені правила..."_. Перелік питань насправді є проблемами, що виражені у форматі питань. Я сподіваюсь, що цей перелік проблем допоможе краще осягнути питання й дати якомога більш правильну відповідь.

Comment: Мені це запитання здається надто неконкретним, тому що: (1) зазвичай люди не переймаються тим, щоб _не знати_ чогось, зазвичай вважається, що чим більше людина знає (зокрема слів якоїсь мови), тим краще; (2) звідси питання перетворюється із «знати чи не знати» на «які вивчати в _першу чергу_»; (3) а які потрібні в першу чергу — це залежить від мети (і поточного стану) людини: якщо це іноземець, що хоче мати можливість вести базові діалоги — то це одне, якщо носій, що хоче працювати в певній галузі, то це інше, якщо мета видати себе за місцевого — то це третє, — тобто не зазначені стан і мета.

Answer (score 1):

**Словниковий запас** — це набір слів, яким володіє людина у знайомій їй мові. Словниковий запас, як правило, росте та розвивається з віком, і слугує як практичний і фундаментальний інструмент для спілкування та здобування знань ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81)). Він є як активний (слова, які ми виокристовуємо), так і пасивний (слова, які ми розуміємо). Саме завдяки йому ми можемо читати тексти різних жанрів, саме від свідчить про рівень нашої освідченості.

Також є «Фокальний словниковий запас» — це спеціалізований набір термінів і ознак, який є особливо важливим певній групі людей; з особливим фокусом досвіду чи діяльності.

Гадаю, що в першу чергу кожна людина повинна намагатися збагачувати свій словниковий запас, а особливо потрібно знати термінологію пов'язану із професійною діяльністю (наприклад, я зараз вивчаю багато нових слів пов'язаних із маркетингом та криптовалютами). Чим більше ви можете підібрати синонімів до слова, чи більше ви знаєте фразеологізмів, тим багатшим буде ваш словниковий запас.

Чи брати до уваги слова-історизми? Це ніколи не буде шкідливо для розвитку вашого світогляду, бо деякі із цих слів напряму пов'язані із історією нашої країни. Чи варто вивчати діалектизми? Гадаю, що так. Як мінімум для того, щоб без проблем розуміти людей з різних регіонів України. І якщо ви знаєте слово "вічний" та "зелений", то, гадаю, у вас не винекне труднощів, щоб дати визначення слову "вічнозелений". Ну і звичайно, потрібно вміти відмінювати слова, потрібно знати слова-омоніми (для уникнення певних непорозумінь та спантеличення).

Я веду до того, що немає якихось обмежень чи правил — все залежить від людини. Саме тому моя відповідь є суб'єктивною. Однак, як вже я писав, словниковий запас напряму залежить від рівня освідченості людини:

> Дослідження 1995 року оцінило розмір словникового запасу мовця,
>   навченого в інституті, на рівні 17 000 словникових гнізд, а
>   студента-першокурсника (що закінчив школу) — 12 000.

Ось ще трохи цифр і досліджень:

> Дослідження показують разючу відмінність у словниковому запасі
>   дошкільнят між різними соціальними класами в Україні. Дошкільнята з
>   сімей інтелектуальної праці зазвичай знають 2 150 різних слів,
>   дошкільнята з робітничих сімей — 1 250 слів, тоді як дошкільнята з
>   господарств, які живуть на соціальні виплати, — 620.
>
> Американські лінгвісти з'ясували, що до 20-ти років
>   середньостатистична людина знає близько 42 тисяч слів у їх словникової
>   формі. Потім вона вивчає нове слово кожні 2 дні ([джерело](https://news.vash.ua/news/nauka-ta-it/slovnykovyy-zapas-lyudyny-otsinyly-u-42-tysyachi-sliv-37535)).

Але врахуйте, що у дошкільняти словниковий запас може складатися не з 2150-ти різних слів, а з 5000, а в 20-річного не 40 тисяч, а, наприклад, лише 25 тисяч. Як я вже писав - все залежить від людини, а саме — від її бажання вчитися.